# How do I get different django admins to play nicely with each other?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, mixins, django-import-export

I am trying to use `django-import-export` and `django-admin-sortable2`, but they do not seem to work simultaneously.

I first had this:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin
class PageAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
```

And import and export both appear and function as expected.  I then added `SortableAdminMixin`:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin
class PageAdmin(SortableAdminMixin,ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
```

The sortable functionality appeared, but this seemed to conflict with the import functionality, and the import button disappeared. I tried re-ordering:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin
class PageAdmin(SortableAdminMixin,ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
```

And this time the items were no longer sortable, but the import button re-appeared.  I've also tried separating import and export:

```
from import_export.admin import ExportActionModelAdmin, ImportMixin
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin
class PageAdmin(ImportMixin,SortableAdminMixin,ExportActionModelAdmin):
```

But to no avail.  How do I get these admin mixins to play nicely with each other?

The functions that each mixin has:

[SortableAdminMixin](https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2/blob/master/adminsortable2/admin.py):

```
def change_list_template(self):
def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
def _get_update_url_name(self):
def get_urls(self):
def get_actions(self, request):
def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
def media(self):
def _add_reorder_method(self):
def update_order(self, request):
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
def move_to_exact_page(self, request, queryset):
def move_to_back_page(self, request, queryset):
def move_to_forward_page(self, request, queryset):
def move_to_first_page(self, request, queryset):
def move_to_last_page(self, request, queryset):
def _get_order_direction(self, request):
def _move_item(self, request, startorder, endorder):
def get_extra_model_filters(self, request):
def get_max_order(self, request, obj=None):
def _bulk_move(self, request, queryset, method):
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
def get_update_url(self, request):
```

[ImportMixin](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/admin.py)

```
def get_skip_admin_log(self):
def get_tmp_storage_class(self):
def get_urls(self):
def get_resource_kwargs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
def get_import_resource_kwargs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
def get_resource_class(self):
def get_import_resource_class(self):
def get_import_formats(self):
def process_import(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
def process_dataset(self, dataset, confirm_form, request, *args, **kwargs):
def process_result(self, result, request):
def generate_log_entries(self, result, request):
def add_success_message(self, result, request):
def get_import_context_data(self, **kwargs):
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
def import_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

It looks like the only common function is get_urls - could this be where the conflict is?

Comment: this packages are hugely over rated. The best way to dump and export data is at the database level

Comment: I have non-technical collaborators, for whom point and click (incl. filtering thru admin interface) seems better than shell commands.

Comment: ever heard of graphical database clients?